# Xcode ViewController and iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I am new to Xcode and to be honest it feels easy and very nice. The workspace is very good,much better that Eclipse. However I have a problem. Despiting choosing the IOs app for iPhone devices, the size of the view controllers and the size of IOs simulator isn't like iPhones. I mean, the view controller looks like a tablet and the iOS simulator looks like an iPhone, however it is veeery big and it does not display all the properties I added.

I also tried rescaling the it by changing the simulated size to freeform but it did not fix my project! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `ViewController` scene in `MainStoryBoard`,and open Utilities window,then select the Attribute inspector,in that you will see the first option as size,in that select the as your simulator size

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default scale is 100%. Go to iOS Simulator > Window > Scale

[image]

Some handy shortcuts -

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for 100%
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for 75%
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for 50%
<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> for Homescreen

There's a lot more to it. Refer to [Testing Retina and Non-Retina Display Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH3-SW1). Here's the scoop -

> On a Mac without a Retina display, when you run iOS device with Retina
>   display - the simulator appears twice as large as it would for a
>   non-Retina display app to account for the extra pixels in a Retina
>   display.

Answer (score 1):

The view controllers will look bigger than an iPhone by default in Xcode 6, that is because it is using size class which allows you to design one view controller for multiple device form factors.

As @raurora suggested your simulator looks huge because your screens resolution is smaller than an iPhone's screen resolution hence you will need to scale the simulator down to fit your screen.

Comment: thank you mate.however the problem is that in the simulator the screen does not appear as I hoped it would. For example: let say that on the control view I add 6 buttons in a row, on the simulator I only see the first 4 buttons. It does not display the other two. I tried to rescale it but still the same problem